# Can't make an absolutely positioned element take the whole height of the container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make the `.info` pane take the whole height of its container which is `.card`, I was able to make this work by giving `.card { position: absolute; }`, but I can't have the `.card` be absolute because I am going to have a list of these cards and with `position:absolute;` they just stack on top of each other. Here is the code:

### HTML

```html
<div class="project-list">
  <div class="card">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="info-section">
      <h3 class="title">Project Title</h3>
      <p class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate ut perspiciatis est sit architecto molestiae illo debitis accusantium laboriosam labore!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="info-section">
      <span>Technologies used: <ul>
        <li>ReactJs</li>
        <li>Express</li>
        <li>Redux</li>
        <li>MongoDB</li>
        </ul></span>
    </div>
    <div class="info-section">
      <div class="github-url">Github Url: <a href="www.github.com">www.github.com</a></div>
      <div class="demo">Click to Open Demo</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570419844482-a232abf0b402?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.card .info {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ff729f;
  z-index: -1;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.info::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}

.info::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}

.info::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.card:hover .info,
.card:active .info {
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 10px -1px rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.75);
}

.card:hover .img-container {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.card:hover .img-container img {
  box-shadow: unset;
}

.card .info .info-section {
  border-bottom: 0.8px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.8);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card .info .info-section:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.card .info .info-section .demo {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .img-container {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: 100%;
  transition: 100ms ease-in;
  background-color: #blue;
  float: right;
}

.card .img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: -10px 0 8px -1px rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.75);
}
```

I can't give `.card` a static `height` because it has to be fully responsive.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could solve this is by changing the `position` in `.card` to `relative`. The disadvantage to this is needing to declare a `height`. I see you said no static height, but a percentage would also work and help to keep your page somewhat responsive.

```
.card {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, if there is no other way I will just use js to calculate a new height on window resize. I just wondered if the problem could be solved without js.